# Perl: Downloading all .jpgs from a web directory

Tags: perl, file, download

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use FindBin qw($Bin);
print $Bin;
my $folder = "$Bin/Resources";
mkdir($folder, 0700) unless(-d $folder );
chdir($folder) or die "can't chdir $folder\n";
my $url = 'http://www.ukgamingcomputers.co.uk/images/zalmanz11plus.jpg';
my $local_file_name = 'pic.jpg';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get( $url, ":content_file" => $local_file_name );
```

I am currently using this code to download a .jpg and put it in a folder called Resources. I want to download all the .jpgs in the http://www.ukgamingcomputers.co.uk/images/ directory. I have absolutely no idea how I would achieve this. If you have a code solution, I would be grateful!

Comment: What happens when you use the code snippet that you've given above?

Comment: I am currently using the code to download pic.jpg and put it in a folder called Resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that. It is also unlikely that the web site owner would want you to.

There is no practical problem with downloading an image in that path, but to fetch them all you need to know what they are called, and there is no way to get a directory listing using `HTTP`.

You *could* crawl the site, fetch all the HTML pages from it, and find the names of all the image files those pages link to, but that would be awkward to do and even less likely to be acceptable to the site owner. It would also get you only the images used on the site, and not all the images in the directory.

Some HTTP servers are configured to return a listing of the directory in HTML if no specific file is specified in the URL and there is no default `index.html` file to send, but that is unusual nowadays as it represents a security breach.

If you think the site owner won't mind you helping yourself to his pictures, why not just send an email asking for a copy of them?

Comment: I don't really want the pictures, I am just experimenting with perl. Maybe I should try a different project if this is considered unacceptable?

Comment: @LukeSilver I think you're fine doing this on larger sites. Like google, yahoo, etc... I figured this was scholastic-like

Comment: @chrsblck: That is very bad advice. Google, for instance, protect their services quite aggressively, and their terms of service say *“Do not misuse our Services, for example, do not interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide.”*

Comment: @Borodin Fair enough, I take that back then.

Comment: @LukeSilver: Most site owners are reasonable about automated access to their sites, and are happy with people running programs that fetch a few bits of information and place *no more load on their servers than a human operator at a browser would*. But downloading the complete graphic resources of an entire site without even a pause between requests is pushing your luck.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use `WWW::Mechanize`?

Here's an example with `HTML::LinkExtor` and `LWP::Simple`

EDIT: This actually pulls all images from given address.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::LinkExtor;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent=1;

die "usage: $0 url\n" if @ARGV != 1;
my $url = shift;
$|++;

if ( $url !~ /^http/ ) { 
  print "usage: url ( http(s)://www.example.com/  )\n"; 
  exit(1);
}

my %images = (); 
my $html = get($url) 
  or die "could not get $url\n";

my $parser = HTML::LinkExtor->new(undef, $url);
$parser->parse($html);

my @all_link_refs = $parser->links();

for my $link_ref ( @all_link_refs  ) { 
  my ( $html_tag, $attr_name, $this_url ) = @$link_ref;
  if ( ($html_tag eq 'img') ) { 
    my $image_name = (split("/", $this_url))[-1];
    $images{$image_name}++;

    if ( $images{$image_name} == 1  ) { 
        print "Downloading $this_url to $image_name...\n";
        open my $PIC, ">", "$image_name";
        my $image = get($this_url);
        print $PIC $image;
    }   
  }
}
```

OUPUT:

```
$ test.pl http://google.com
Downloading http://google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png to logo1w.png...
```

Comment: This doesn't do what was asked. It just fetches all the files specified in the `src` attribute of an `img` element of a given HTML page.

Comment: @Borodin Correct. I interpreted the question a bit. The OP's question doesn't make sense, because you'll have to know the name of the file to download. Most likely he's getting `view source` from the webpage. Which would mean it would just be easier to just download directly from the browser.

Comment: Then don't you think you ought to say something about what your code actually does, and that it doesn't do what was asked?

Comment: @Borodin I'd like to point out the title of this Question(What I interprutated was, jpgs = all_images). Which is why my answer is the way it is. Fair advice anyhow. Thanks

Comment: Both the title and the question talk about *“Downloading all [image files] from a web directory”*. That is different from downloading all images linked to by a web page.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of following your example, this pulls jpgs from that site you listed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::Link;
use Getopt::Long;

exit int main( parse_args() );

sub main {
    my $opts = shift;

    my $folder = $opts->{folder};
    chdir($folder) or die "can't chdir $opts->{folder}\n";

    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
    $mech->get( $opts->{url} );

    for my $link ( $mech->links() ) {
        next unless $link->text() =~ /jpg$/;
        $mech->get( $link->url() );
        $mech->save_content( $link->text() );
    }
}

sub parse_args {
    my %opts = (
        url    => "http://www.ukgamingcomputers.co.uk/images/",
        folder => "/home/kprice/tmp",
    );

    GetOptions( \%opts, 'url|u=s', 'folder|d=s', ) or die $!;

    return \%opts;
}
```

If you're on linux, this would work, but pull everything from that link:

`$ wget -r http://www.ukgamingcomputers.co.uk/images/`

EDIT: I corrected it a little after that quick copy/paste.

Comment: *Please* don't teach people how to misuse other people's internet property.